# Systeme error: displaying different equation than coded

Tags: equations, systeme

When I enter the following line of code in LaTeX for displaying a system I get a strange error. And yes, I don't know why it is in French.

Code:

```
$\systeme*{-2x+7 = y, -3x-2x+7-12 = 0}$
```

Error:

> ```
> Package systeme Error: l'inconnue "x_{-1}" a deja ete trouvee dans l'equation!.
> $\systeme*{-2x+7 = y, -3x-2x+7-12 = 0}
> ```

Comment: isn't it complaining about the two instances of x in the second equation (-3x-2x)

Comment: `systeme` is great for typesetting linear systems in canonical form. When the form is not the canonical one, there's no sensible alignment to do.

Comment: The package author is French. Maybe he forgot to translate some of the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source of your problem is second equation in your equation systeme. I suspect, that you like to obtain:

[image]

Correct syntax for above equations is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
$\systeme*{-2x     + 7 = y,
          {-3x -2x} + {7 - 12} = 0}$         
\end{document}
```